# Websites use server or client hardware resources?

Tags: resources, cpu, hardware, cpu-usage, ram

When a user visits a website which runs an intensive script, does the web server handle it by using its own CPU and RAM, or does it use the users' resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether the script is written in a server-side or client-side scripting language.

For example, if the website uses an intensive php script it will run on the server as PHP is a server-side scripting language whereas Javascript is a client-side scripting language which will run on the clients web browser using the clients resources.

Server-side scripts typically need to access resources on the server, such as the database. The script will execute, process everything it needs to and then send the results to the client to be rendered by their browser.

Client-side scripts will typically effect data or UI elements already rendered on the clients screen (pop-up alert on button press, form validation, etc) which does not require any sort of server communication.